# How do I sort Firefox bookmarks alphabetically by manipulating the 'json' or 'places.sqlite' files via the terminal?

Tags: command-line, firefox, bookmarks

is there a way possible with `terminal pipelining` to sort the bookmarks `Mozilla Firefox`stores in `alphabetical` order?

I tried dabbing a little but to my disappointment ,the `bookmarks` are stored in `JSON` format ,how do you extract things from that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you state what your final goal is, you will get better answers. You can get a somewhat clean list of sorted URLs from a JSON file with something like:

```
sed 's/,/\n/g' bookmarks-2012-07-07.json | grep '"uri"' | grep http | cut -d '"' -f 4 | sort
```

Your most powerful option is to utilize sqlite3 to get the bookmarks from the file places.sqlite from your home directory.

Comment: wow ,is that the regex power coming into picture or am i missing something ?

Comment: Assume his computer with Firefox only boots up in console mode now, no GUI. But he still wants to sort his bookmarks alphabetically with what he has. There you have it ;)

Comment: i know it will be too much to ask but can you just explain how does that work  out ?

Comment: `sed` is a powerful stream editor, used above only to substitute one string with another. You can utilize regex with sed, but the example given doesn't do that much (even though a single character typically does qualify as a REGEX).

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to sort the bookmarks *in Firefox* alphabetically, it's very easy to do and no command-line magic is necessary.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (<--letter O) to open the Bookmarks Library.
2. Navigate to the folder you want to sort, right-click on it and click on "Sort by Name":

   [image]
3. Those bookmarks will be sorted alphabetically. Notice the before/after difference:

   [image]

Comment: Well thats not what i wanted izk ,but thanks anyways ,i wanted to do it via terminal

Comment: OK, fixed the title for you.

Comment: Note that the *backups* are in json, the actual bookmarks are stored in **places.sqlite** as Marios explained in his answer.